# How do I get my Clock & Weather widget on my homescreen?

Tags: app-widgets

I used to have a widget for Clock & Weather on my home screen but it vanished. I am trying to set it up again, but I am not successful. I am seeing that you need to press down on home screen and select widget am on Android 4.0.4, but all I get is "Choose wallpaper from".

I miss my widget. How can I get my widget back?

My device is an *Infinix Race Bolt 450* running Android 4.0.4. The "App Drawer" has a widget tab, but the widget is not listed there. It is installed, however, as the app providing it is still there and working.

Comment: Some apps allow you to chose what widgets should be enabled (I know that e.g. from *Business Calendar*). Can you start the app and check in its settings if the widget might be switched-off by accident?

Comment: Workaround: there are apps in the play store that will put a widget with similar functionality on your home screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to :**

- Press Home button followed by Menu button. Select Add -> Widgets ->
  Clock & Weather.

**Or :**

- Press Home button to show the home screen. Tap and hold your finger
  on any available space, select Widgets -> Clock & Weather.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Menu button only gives me  Wallpaper , Manage Apps and System Setting                                                        Tap and hold Home screen just gives option of choosing wallpaper

Comment: Do you have a Widget tab when you go in your applications? In the top right corner.

Comment: If you have Jelly beans 4.2 have a look at this : http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/11/19/how-to-use-lock-screen-widgets-in-android-4-2-jelly-bean/

Comment: am using Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.4 Widget tab is available and i can select all other widgets e.g. calendar but my Weather & Clock widget is missing.  on the app under settings--> Widget settings i believe i have the correct settings

Comment: Are you sure Weather & Clock is installed? Try to re-install it.

Comment: yes it is and on the App itself it works ok, wanted an easier way of checking weather by having widget.